# Getting the total number of identical items in a table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table that is setup like

```
id | upc | count
----------------
1  | 100 |  5
2  | 100 | 12
3  | 101 |  3
4  | 100 |  7
```

and I would like to get the sum of the individual upc's

Expected output:

```
upc | count
--- | -----
100 | 24
101 |  3
```

and I'm not really sure how to go about it.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I had been doing it by making manually adding all the rows in a php array, for some reason it didn't occur to me that I could use sum like that.  Thanks for the help :)

Comment: You're right, it is a duplicate, when I was searching I found some other questions using group_concat, but that wasn't what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use GROUP BY and the [SUM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) aggregate function:

```
SELECT upc, SUM(count) AS count
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY upc
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT upc,SUM(count) FROM table GROUP BY upc ;
```

Edit: No need to use backticks in this case (`count` is a valid column name).

Comment: That's not true. count is *not* a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html). It's true that there are many good reasons to avoid using `count` as a column name, but it's perfectly legal. Quote from manual:  "For example, COUNT is acceptable as a column name."

Comment: @MarkByers you're right, from the long list of reserved words `COUNT` is not one of them. I'll correct this.